# Macro to move selected outlook emails

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have the following macro for saving attachments, it works fine but I would like it to move the emails to another folder once the attachments have been saved. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveFolderAttachments()

  ' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
  Dim oShell As Object
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
  Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
  If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

  ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
  Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
  If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  ' Iteration variables
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSavePathFS As String
  Dim sDelAtts

  For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

    sDelAtts = ""

    ' We check each msg for attachments as opposed to using .Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
    ' on our olPurgeFolder.Items collection.  The collection returned by the Restrict method
    ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
    ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
    ' This is why the For Each loops will not work.
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

      ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method
      ' which will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time.
      While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

        ' Save the file
        sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
        msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

        ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
        ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
        If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
        Else
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
        End If

        ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
        ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
        ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
        ' the behavior.
        msg.Attachments(1).Delete

      Wend

      ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
      ' the deleted attachments.
      If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
        msg
      Else
        msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
      End If

      ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.
      msg.Save

    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call MailItem.Move(MAPIFolder) to move a message. Do not use a "for each' loop if youi move the messages (since the collection count changes), use a down loop (for I = Items.Count to 1 step -1)

EDIT:

```
Dim objItems as Outlook.Items 
set objItems = olPurgeFolder.Items
for I = objItems.Count to 1 step -1
  set msg = objItems.Item(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Alot! One last question where should I put this into my code? As I am currently getting a variable not defined error regarding the "I" in the "for I = objItems.Count to 1 step -1" line?

Comment: add "dim i" to the top of the function